# Whats the range of dimension exponents in the SI system of units?

Tags: si-units, units

I am working on a software library for Units of Measure. To represent dimensions, I need to know the required range of exponents for each of the seven base units (precisely, I need to know the required maximum number of bits for each exponent). After reading many related questions, I still have some questions.

As far as I understand, all physical quantities can be expressed as the product of the seven base units, with each base unit raised to the power of $0$, $\pm1$, $\pm2$, $\pm3$, and so on. So the dimension of a quantity is represented by a vector / array of 7 integers.

E.g. for volume (length ^ 3) that array would be (3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), for acceleration (length / (time ^ 2)) it would be (1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).

While I could calculate the square of a volume (with dimension 6,0,0,..), it doesn't make much sense, because I have never encountered any physical quantity that needs (length ^ 6).

My questions:

- a) What is the maximum required exponent for Length? Do you know any example where $\pm3$ is not enough?
- b) Maximum exponent for Time? Any example beyond $\pm4$?
  *(update: raised to 4 for capacitance)*
- c) Maximum exponent for Mass? Any example beyond $\pm1$?
- d) Maximum exponent for Electric Current? Any example beyond $\pm1$?
- e) Maximum exponent for Temperature? Any example beyond $\pm4$?
  *(update: raised to 4 for Stefan-Boltzmann constant)*
- f) Maximum exponent for Amount of Substance? Any example beyond $\pm1$?
- g) Maximum exponent for Luminous Intensity? Any example beyond $\pm1$?

... plus three bonus questions:

- h) Is there some required order of the seven base units? I have seen more than one ordering in use.
- i) Are those seven base units enough for everything, or is there some bleeding-edge science that needs more?
- j) Are the exponents always integral? Never ever something like ^ 1.5 or ^e?

(update)
I guess I should clarify:
I am aware that **values** might need rational or real exponents.
I am aware that **intermediate** results might need a wider range of integer exponents.
I have read the relevant SI standard document, and lots of websites about the topic.

My questions are just about the base units exponents that define the dimension of (base or derived) units.

The most precise statement I found so far was: *the exponents are very small integers*.

However, to exploit all filthy speed tricks of CPU or GPU assembly programming, I need to know the exact number of bits required.

Comment: A combination of these two pages may be of some use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis

Comment: Take also a look at http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html , it has many examples that go beyond the limits you suggest, and is a good reading for anyone writing software related to SI units.

Comment: Do you need the SI decomposition only for checking dimensional mismatches or also for anything else? I have written a physics units library that uses cgs as its internal system, which works quite well and has less computional overhead than a full SI representation. (You can still auto-convert to better-suited units of any kind for the final output.) — What you definitely need is larger exponents than 6 (I'd recommend at least 12), and support for fractional exponents – even when no unit with an actual physical meaning has such a dimension, it may still occur in intermediate results.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Right now i use a dimension class that contains an array of seven signed bytes, so every exponent can be -128 to +127. However my gut feeling tells me that this might be way beyond whats actually needed. The Dimension class will be used at compile-time and run-time to avoid / detect doing silly things. I am curious how you solved the issue, is your library somewhere on the web ?

Comment: @MillKa: there are many open-source unit libraries out there on the web that you can look at for inspiration. A web search for **[your language] units** might be a good place to start.

Comment: @Dave Zaslavsky: Thanks for the tip. I've already checked out several libraries.  I have some different ideas about the internal implementation details.  If all works out as planned, all units (meter, feet, ..) for the same quantity (length) will be one type with automatic conversion.  Units for different quantities will be different types (for static type checking at compile time), so you cant add speed to volume.  Most of that static checking is implemented in a way so that it is going to be optimized away at the compiler and/or jitter stage, resulting in a speed very close to

Comment: .. pure floating point arithmetic.  The full dimensional representation needs to be reduced to the required minimum number of bits for efficiency reasons, so that valid operations are almost as fast as pure floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Well, that sounds like much more of a high-speed solution than my library. At first, I actually thought about doing all the unit checking at compile-time too when I conceived it, but then found that it was too difficult when it came to more complex calculation, so I switched to doing this dynamically. That's much slower, but I'm also doing dynamic measurement-uncertainty calculations anyway so it does not matter _too_ much. If the unit stuff is compile-time, you should not get any runtime overhead even if you use a full array of 7 `int` variables. Don't over-optimize it if it's no use!

Comment: In stellar physics exponents of $40$ or so are found in some proportionality relations, with obvious implications for the dimension of the proportionality constant, so I think much of what you're trying to do here is unworkable. I've also seen quite general fractional exponents in field theories' energy-entropy relations.

Answer (score 7):

At least one common quantity I can think of has dimension with a non-integer exponent. The [specific detectivity, $\text{D}^*$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_detectivity) is a common descriptor of photodiodes, and I'm sure one could make an analogous figure of merit for other types of sensor.

The unit of $\text{D}^*$ is the "Jones," which is equal to

$$\frac{cm \cdot \sqrt{Hz}}{W}$$

Watts in SI decompose into

$$Kg \cdot m^2 \cdot s^{-3}$$

which makes one Jones equal to:

$$\frac{s^{2.5}}{Kg \cdot m} \times 10^{-2}$$

with dimension:

$$\text{time}^{2.5} \text{mass}^{-1} \text{length}^{-1}$$

There are other quantities related to $\text{D}^*$, such as Noise Equivalent Power (NEP), which come up a lot in radiometry. Basically, any measurement which is normalized by frequency bandwidth will end up with that $\sqrt{Hz}$ in the units.

Comment: Seconding this, root-hertz is pretty common in spectroscopy, noise levels in electronics, etc. Common fractional power unit.

Comment: Ouch. So how is the relation to SI handled ? Is there another "SI compatible" unit, e.g. square Jones ?

Comment: @MillKa: What do you mean "relation to SI"? This *is* SI.

Comment: @Dan: Oops. Translation error. I just checked the english text of the SI brochure ( http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf ) and it says the exponents ".. are **generally** small integers ..", but that got lost in the translated version I used.  If I switch from integer to fixed point exponents, I could cover 1/2 and my speedups would still work.  But if I have to support all possible fractions or even irrational numbers, the speedups will not be possible any more.

Comment: @millka: I agree with Dan. Fractional exponents are completely valid in any system of units. Especially if you are writing a general library for handling units, you cannot make any assumptions about how people will use them. I probably invent a"new" figure of merit once a week, with its associated units. Task-specific units are perfectly valid, and you cannot guess at their dimension ahead of time. At best, you may be able to place some broad limits on this; maybe the exponent has to be rational? Our maybe it must only be real? In any event, your array of exponents must be floating point.

Comment: Correction: as you said, fixed point would probably be ideal.

Comment: However, the fact that you are concerned with making dimensional calculations faster makes me think you are doing something wrong. If I've got to multiply two arrays with a million elements each, I do not want to repeat the dimensional calculations for each element of the array! It will always be sufficient to handle dimensional analysis independantly from the numerical calculations.

Comment: The dimension speedup idea was to cram all seven exponents into one 32-bit int (e.g. exp = +-7 = 4 bit x 7 base units = 28 bits). Then almost all dimension calculations could have been simple integer operations (+, -, ==).  Real number exponents would be a real pain, because comparing floating point numbers for equality is calling for trouble.  I have to check how far i can get with rational numbers stored as fixed point numbers.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I'm still concerned about why you care about optimizing this calculation so much. I appreciate efficient code, but this is not something that should need to be computed very often. In most cases, the dimension of a the result of a computation is known even before the calculation is done. You could do the dimensional analysis once, and sure the result.

Comment: The "dimensional signature" (the 7 exponents crammed into one integer (32, 64 or even 128 bit)) would be computed only once, when a quantity type is defined.  After that, the signature only needs to be compared to another signature (or the sum or difference of two signatures). When handling huge vectors, the overloaded operator function would check the signature just once per vector, not once per vector element. The signature would have also been used as key for internal tables and as a type parameter that tells the compilers static type checking if two types are the same quantity or not.

Comment: @MillKa let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/687/discussion-between-colin-k-and-millka)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you really need it, here's what I have found to be usable:

As I said, I represent all units internally as cgs:
$$
  \mathrm{U} = \mathrm{cm}^c\cdot \mathrm{g}^g\cdot\mathrm{s}^s
$$
Where, in general, $c,g,s\in\mathbb{Q}$.
For this, I have 3 `int`s, defined by
$$
  i_c = 39916800 \cdot c
$$
etc., so that, $39916800$ being $11!$, I can be almost completely sure that nobody will ever come up with a unit such that $i_c\not\in\mathbb{Z}$. It also supports exponents up to $\frac{2^{31}}{11!}\approx 53$, which I'm quite sure should be enough.

You may argue that using full integer variables is a great waste of resources, but I actually think (haven't tried it, though) that it's faster than a naïvely implemented array of `char`s, because the processor does not even directly calculate those, if you ask it to: it first needs to cast them to `int`, do the calculation there, and cast them back to `char`.

And as I said, you probably don't need to worry *at all* about performance if you do the unit stuff at compile time. The quantities do not need any knowledge about their SI exponentials whatsoever then, and if you need some way to uniquely identify units, you can just put all the units that actually occur during the preprocessing in a hash map or something and let the calculable quantities store only pointers to the unit objects.

Comment: If you use 12252240 instead of 39916800, then you can handle all exponents up to ≈ 175 with denominators up to 18.

Comment: Because 12252240 is the least common multiple of numbers $1$ to $18$? Reasonable thought, but I deliberately chose a faculty rather than an lcm, because it seems more likely to me to get something like $\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt[5]{\sqrt{}}}}}}=()^{\frac{1}{8\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 2}}$ rather than $\sqrt[13]{}$.

Answer (score 2):

The range for the exponents you need is (- infinity , + infinity). Units for school physics will mostly use signed integer in the range of [-3,+3] but in thermodynamics and quantum mechanics one may look at many dimensions. 
Perhaps you can find some ideas how others solved the problem in units. http://linux.die.net/man/1/units

Keep in mind, that some values might be tensors or vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just use integers in all cases.  For example the statcoulomb, the gaussian unit of charge, is defined as

$1 \text{ statcoulomb} = \frac{g^{1/2} cm^{3/2}} {s}$.

Also,the Stefan-Boltzmann constant's units are proportional to $T^{-4}$. Specifically, [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):
$$\sigma = 5.670400 \times 10^{-8}J s^{-1}m^{-2}K^{-4}$$

Comment: Thanks.  But isn't that a problem of the CGS unit system (and other non-SI unit systems) ? [statcoulomb @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb)

Comment: I don't know of any fractional dimensions in the SI system.  Is your program restricted to SI?

Comment: Yes, I will stick to SI. At least in the core of the library, so that i can use integer exponents for the dimensions.  Otherwise half of my speedup ideas wouldn't work.  I think a pure SI library would be still useful enough.

Comment: ""Thanks. But isn't that a problem of the CGS unit system (and other non-SI unit systems) ? "" Statcoulombs are statcoulombs, irrespective of cgs or mks! The "difference" is somwhere other, You should read about such things first. The fact that such things are not used today is not beause of MKS, its because textbook-writers decided to stop it, in order not to ask for too much from amateurs/beginners. I must confess, that this kind of natural units were very confusing to me when I began to learn physics.

Comment: @Georg: I tend to conflate the two; I almost never see CGS unless Gaussian or natural units are also being employed.

Comment: When I tinker around with old radios (detectors and the like) I use "cm" as a capacitance unit frequently, just because this is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

In a paper, dated yesterday, where units are studied I can see wavelength raised to -5 , temperature raised to 4.
I do not know the actual maximum exponents in all circumstances.

**Constant or Quantity --- Dimension**

Planck Constant *h*  --- $ML^{2}T^{-1}$
Stefan Constant $\sigma$ ---  $MT^{-3}\theta^{-4}$
Boltzmann Constant *k* --- $ML^{2}T^{-2}\theta^{-1}$
Temperature $\theta$  --- $\theta$
Energy  --- $ML^{2}T^{-2}$
Force  ---  $MLT^{-2}$
Pressure  --- $ML^{-1}T^{-2}$
Luminosity --- $MT^{-3}$
Power  --- $ML^{2}T^{-3}$
Velocity  --- $LT^{-1}$
Electron charge  --- $Q$
Proton mass ---  $M$
Bohr radius  --- $L$

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on the development of a namespace for quantities and units and I stumbled upon this old discussion.

My small and late contribution:

a)-g) The exponent for length can be as high as six (dipole-dipole interaction, such as in Fluorescence Resonance Energy Transfer). The exponent for current / charge can be +-2 (capacitance, resistance, permittivity, permeability, Coulomb constant) and I guess the same can happen to Mass. In Chemistry, the thermodynamic equilibrium constant has dimensions equal to a power of the pressure, or of the molar concentration, with an exponent equal to the difference in the stoichiometric coefficient, which is limited by the reaction order. For a single reaction, the maximum reaction order observed is 6 (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-order-of-reaction; http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01304a016); for a reaction chain, it can be unlimited (think about polymers...)

h) I think the crystallised order is L M T I Θ N J with exponents

i) Maybe also units for angles and logarithmic units (bel, nit, digit, bit) could be included, but I am in doubt.

j) I never saw exponents other than integers and half-integers (square roots) but maybe they occur in mixed-order chemical reactions.

Answer (score 0):

*(Perhaps OP should have posted separate questions back in the day, but here we are.)*

> i) Are those seven base units enough for everything, or is there some bleeding edge science that needs more ?

**No**, the seven base units are not enough for everything.  But there doesn't need to be any bleeding-edge science involved.  One of the base units, the [mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)), isn't actually a unit of the quantity it measures -- "amount of substance".

A table in [the Wikipedia article on SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) describing base quantities has the most recent definition of the mole from the relevant SI document:

> The amount of substance of exactly $6.02214076×10^{23}$ elementary entities<sup>3</sup>.

But there's a footnote:

> 3. **When the mole is used, the elementary entities must be specified** and may be atoms, molecules, ions, electrons, other particles, or specified groups of such particles.

The mole is more of a schema for creating units than an actual unit. You never just have a "mole", you have to have a mole of *something specific*.

Avogadro's constant is just a count.   Unless you specify the type of elementary entity you're counting (and only one of the types useful in chemistry) it doesn't give rise to a useful "amount of substance".  So technically, there's a different base quantity for every type of elementary entity being measured.

There are plenty of other things that are counted in science, but since they're not used in chemistry or physics, they never got baked into SI.  And you can't measure them in moles, [except whimsically](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/).

There's an analogy in axiomatic set theory: Two of the [Zermelo-Frankel "axioms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) aren't really axioms at all.  They're axiom schemata, and generate a different axiom for each property under consideration.